# Using Heroku over AWS for salesforce intergration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, heroku, salesforce

My website done in PHP is currently deployed in AWS server.
Client wants to move it to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for integrating the database with Salesforce.

Is it really necessary?
Salesforce have their API by which I can sync data from my project's MySQL database to Salesforce database. 
Will moving the project to Heroku provide any extra advantages that AWS doesn't have ?

thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no special advantages in approach which your client provide. In both cases you will need to implement logic for integration and interaction with SF part, and I don't see any benefits in migration to Heroku, but I see additional work for migration your current infrastructure.

Although Heroku provides some features for integration with SF out of the box, it seems to me, it will be cheaper and easier to add SF integration to your current project. But it's depends on many factors (for example, how is fit the Heroku platform for your solution at all), so possible best way is to implement PoC for both cases (if it's possible) and compare it.